# Can't import both sstream and iostream in C++20?

Tags: c++, c++20, iostream, sstream

Create a new empty C++ Windows console application in Visual Studio 2022.

Add a "main.cppm" file and populate it with this:

```
import <sstream>;

int main()
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << "Hey world!";
    return 0;
}
```

It should compile and run fine (though it doesn't do anything useful).

Now comment that out and change the code to this:

```
//import <sstream>;
import <iostream>;

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello world!" << std::endl;
    //std::stringstream ss;
    //ss << "Hey world!";
    return 0;
}
```

Again, it compiles and runs fine and we see "Hello world!" on the console.

But now uncomment the commented lines:

```
import <sstream>;
import <iostream>;

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello world!" << std::endl;
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << "Hey world!";
    return 0;
}
```

This will NOT compile, giving the following errors:

> E0070 incomplete type is not allowed

(referring to `stringstream`)

> E0349 no operator "<<" matches these operands

> E3365 incomplete class type "std::basic_stringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>" is not allowed

and the following message:

> Local variable is not initialized

(referring to the `ss` variable)

It compiles fine if I:

1. `#include <sstream>` and `import <iostream>;`, or
2. `#include <iostream>` and `import <sstream>;`, or
3. `#include <iostream>` and `#include <sstream>;`.

But I CANNOT `import <iostream>;` and `import <sstream>;` at the same time.

Can anyone explain why, or know how to import both? I suspect this has to do with a dependency between the two, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Exxxx diagnostics are not compile errors, merely spew from the Intellisense parser.  This is very new, so liable to have trouble, file bug reports with Help > Send Feedback.

Comment: Thanks Hans. I am fairly new to C++ as it is and wasn’t sure if I was doing something wrong.

Comment: Why `import` and just just `#include` headers to begin with?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin [Overview of modules in C++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/modules-cpp?view=msvc-170)

Comment: @ToddBurch most standard library units are available via `import std.core;`

Comment: @RemyLebeau - thank you. A MS compiler thing. I've never run into a problem using `#include` with `cl.exe` or `gcc` or any other compiler, so I was a bit curious why the choice of one over the other. The independently compiled set of sources sounds interesting -- though I'm a little fuzzy on the problems with header files it is supposed to cure. Explains why `g++` puked on the source right off the bat `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin when your projects start getting large, compile times get prohibitively slow when using headers (as well as being very inefficient). C++20 modules are designed to solve this (as well as a few other issues).

Comment: @RemyLebeau I haven’t had success getting std.core to work yet, plus I think importing only the modules in use better documents the needs of the code—but I may end up heading that direction.

Comment: I would avoid modules for another year or two, especially if you're new to C++. They are not widely/properly supported yet. If you have issues with build times, make sure you're using PCH.

Comment: It does tend to make one speculate what the origin of modules was when the linked page explains "Before it was specified by the C++20 standard, Microsoft had experimental support for modules in the Microsoft C++ compiler. " Though the page cautions that for existing larger existing projects to "Base your adoption on whether you get a meaningful reduction in compilation times." Will be nice to experiment with and see what can be obtained.

Comment: @ToddBurch: Importing standard library components as header units is *supposed* to work, but it doesn't really work well on most implementations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested with MSVC 2022 Version 17.5.4 and
17.6.0 Preview 5.0.

**Edit**: IDE says that C++ IntelliSense support for C++20 Modules is currently experimental.

The code compiles and runs.

`Scan Sources for Module Dependencies` needs to be Yes.

You can change this option as follows:

Menu -> Project -> Properties ->
Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> All Options ->
`Scan Sources for Module Dependencies` -> Yes.

[image: Scan Sources for Module Dependencies]

Answer (score 0):

This is clearly a bug in Visual Studio, specifically IntelliSense. Note that module support is still incomplete there so until it is fixed you'll have to use includes. In C++23 you'll also be able to do `import std`.

Comment: No, it isn't, not with the information provided. Diagnostics starting wtih E aren't from MSVC (those would be starting with C), but from IntelliSense, which is an IDE feature and not the C++ compiler.

Comment: @Fulgen Please note that the *old* acronym MSVC is commonly (though maybe imprecisely) used to referer to the *whole* Visual Studio IDE (which includes IntelliSense), not just the `cl.exe` compiler, if that is your concern about this answer.

Comment: @Bob__ Hmm, I'm also under impression that it refers to a compiler. For example, see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_C%2B%2B), or [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-msvc).

Comment: Clarified that MSVC refers to VS, not the compiler.

Comment: MSVC generally refers to the Microsoft Visual C++ toolset: the source compiler. See, for example, [this page that uses the acronym](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170). 

It's kind of confusing that Visual Studio has multiple C++ compilers: the IDE (e.g., IntelliSense) uses a different C++ compiler. Using "MSVC" to refer to a bug that manifests specifically in the IDE is confusing.